# Displaying Query and its Explain Plan as a HashMap

Tags: java, sql, sql-execution-plan

I have to generate execution plans for each query extracted from a log file. I have to generate a Hashmap that contains the query as the key and value as the execution plan. This HashMap is to be displayed as a table in Angular.

So far I have tried the following. I am getting the table with query and execution plans as two columns. But the explain plain is displayed in a single line, instead of the table form I get when I print it out on the console (See the picture). Is there a way to get the same format while displaying it in the Angular table.

[image: The Angular table displays the Execution Plans Like this]

**The Console Prints it in this form, which is what I want in the table also.**

[image]

**CODE:**

**ExecutionPlanService**: Connects to the Oracle DB and generates Explain Plan.

```
@Service
public class ExecutionPlanService {
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
String execute;

public List<String> getExecPlan(String line) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ResultSet rs=null;




        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.49.7.212:1521:AVMPRD","CtmDitRW","CtmDit1743");  

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(line);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display())");

        while (rs.next())
        {
            l.add(rs.getString(1));


        }

        return l;


   }
   public String prepend(String line, String prepend){
      String output = null;
       for (int index = 0; index < line.length(); index++) {
          output = prepend + line;
       }
       return output;


     }
     }
```

**ExecPlanService**: Checks if the given line is SQL statement, generates explain plan and puts these both as key and value in a HashMap.

```
private SQLCheckerService checker = new SQLCheckerService();
private ExecutionPlanService service = new ExecutionPlanService();
List<String>l =  new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
String trimmedLine;
public Map<String, List<String>> processLine(String line) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {

     if(this.checker.isSelectStatement(line)) 

    {   
       System.out.println("working!!");

      //Trim the line to start with a SQL keyword
           trimmedLine= this.checker.trimString(line);
           String prepend = this.service.prepend(trimmedLine, "Explain plan for ");
          l =this.service.getExecPlan(prepend); 
          l.forEach(System.out::println);

          map.put(trimmedLine,l );
          System.out.println(map);

   }

    return map;
  }
```

**ReadFileExecPlanService:** Reads a log file line by line and processes it to generate explain plan.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> readFile(String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

private ExecPlanService eservice= new ExecPlanService();
Map<String, List<String>> hashMap =  new HashMap<>();


     try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))){

         for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ){


          hashMap = this.eservice.processLine(line);

         }


       }
     System.out.println(hashMap);
        return hashMap; 
}
```

**ExecPlanController**

```
@RestController
public class ExecPlanController {
@Autowired
ReadFileExecPlan exservice;

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

@GetMapping("/getPlan") 
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, List<String>>  getPlan() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
     String rootLocation = "C:\\Users\\Apoorva_Sharma\\Desktop\\upload-dir";

     File directory = new File(rootLocation);
        //get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList){
            if (file.isFile()){
                map = (exservice.readFile(file.getAbsolutePath())); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("WORKING!!");
        System.out.println(map);
        return map;

      }
      }
```

Comment: You're going to have to parse each row, possibly modify it, and then add it to a collection in Java.  Then, return that collection to your Angular UI.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen you mean each row of the explain plan? How can that be done?

Comment: Your question is very broad, I doubt you'll get an answer in this format.  Break down the problem into smaller pieces.  First, get your output from the query plan query, and arrange in a Java collection in a format which you can then send back to your UI.  Then, worry about Angular later.